# How to quit debug from another session

Tags: matlab, matlab-engine

I use a [Matlab Engine API](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/calling-matlab-engine-from-c-programs-1.html) in order to verify my hdl design. Often, while testing I need to debug some matlab functions. Problem is when I forget to quit debug and then start another simulation, things will go wrong, so I decided to check if matlab is in debug and quit if so via Engine API. I tried this code:

```
if(~isempty(dbstack()))
    dbquit('all')
end
```

which works fine if I test it in my opened Matlab session, but if I run this code via Matlab Engine, I will not quit from debug.
As I understand, problem is when I use API, I create a new session which dbstack is not correspond one from previously opened session so I can't affect on it. Is there a way to solve this problem?